# Could a Matrix mimic this Crystal Report structure - SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to convert a Crystal Report to SSRS and I'm having trouble with this section of the report.

[image: Crystal Report Format]

The first line of the report event information: date, name, recruiter, hours, etc.

And then under the summary, the report should list changes that are considered critical changes to information about the event.  Within Crystal Report, these changes are in the Details section and all changes are listed under each event.

I am trying to accomplish the same task within SSRS but I'm having some trouble with the changes summary. The event summary displays for each record of a change. In the screen shot below, you can see that DriveID 682144 had three changes, but for each change, the event summary is displayed/printed. So instead of Evoqua listed once and the three changes made to the event listed underneath, I am getting the summary displayed for each and every change within the report.

I have a row grouping for DriveID since each event has an unique ID. And I also have a Details row group that displays the changes. I've tried adding a grouping on the Details row group, but if I group on SourceDriveID, it will only display one record for each drive. I am joining the two tables on DriveID (Drivemaster.DriveID=CriticalDriveChanges.SourceDriveID)

I think it would work if the Critical Drive Changes view had a unique identifier, but it doesn't so I am trying to work with what I have. Any suggestions on making this work?

If there is anything I need to explain better, please let me know. I've been stuck on this for two days and need to get through it.

[image: SSRS]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second group needs to be grouped by the key of the “changes” and not the DriveID. It’s already grouped by the DriveID because of the parent group. Grouping by the same Field again effectively gives you an extra summary row, its showing the first of the changes.

Comment: Problem is that there is no key for the changes, it's a view that does not have a primary key.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a primary key from the Changes. 
You can add multiple fields into the "group by" so its unique.
EG use the "Change Date & Time" field and if that's not Unique also add "Changed by" etc...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by customized summary. You can have a global variable for the summary, and use expression to do the calculation. Some tricks are needed for this kind of report.